# cannot use js function twice

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am facing my first java-script problem, that means i am novice.
The problem is that i cannot use java-script function twice.

```
function displaying(id){
    switch(id){
        case 1:
        document.getElementById("foot").style.display = "block";
        break;
        case 2:
        document.getElementById("foot").style.display = "none";
        break;
    }
}
```

I call this function first time while clicking "about us"

```
<b id="about" onclick="displaying(1)" >Biz barada<b>
```

and second time when i try to make display none

```
<img id="close"  onclick="displaying(2)" src="img/close.png">
```

The style of what i am trying to display is by default display:none

Comment: include a `default` case in your switch, also what error exactly are you getting in your browser console? I cannot help you much if you do not provide what the issue is. Thanks

Comment: Why not use a true/false? That way you can use a simpler if condition.

Comment: The function will be getting called twice.  Add some logging, or write to the console inside the function, and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Use an eventListener, I will post the code in a few minutes.
Unless you are using vue or angular and the like, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't closed your `<b>` tag, and hence its always getting the `id` as 1. Below is the updated code:

```js
function displaying(id) {
  console.log(id);
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("foot").style.display = "block";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("foot").style.display = "none";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<b id="about" onclick="displaying(1)">Biz barada</b>

<img id="close" onclick="displaying(2)" src="img/close.png">
<div id="foot">Foot</div>
```